# Revised Simplex: reduced cost and related constraint

Tags: optimization

In the revised simplex method, you can get the reduced costs straightforward from the tableau. I know which they are, but I don't know which reduced cost I should "relate" to which constraint.

Will the leftmost value relate to the 1st constraint, and so on?

Suppose, e.g, you have the following optimal tableau:

```
  X1    2/3   0  1/3   10/3
  X5    2/3   1  1/3   22/3 
  X3    1/3   0  -1/3  8/3
  f(x)  5/3   0  1/3   f(x)+28/3
```

It is a minimization problem with 3 restrictions of the type <=.
I have an exercise that gives me just this info and then asks for the most "meaningful restriction". I know the most "meaningful" is the restriction related to the marginal cost 5/3, as this is the greatest marginal cost in terms of absolute value.

But idk if I could say that "the first" restriction is the one, just because 5/3 is the "first" marginal cost, or maybe the n-th restriction, because I am missing something. I hope this clarifies my doubt.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Thank you for your question.  It will be easier for us to help you if you provide more context for your question.  Different sources may have different definitions for "revised simplex method" or the other terms you used.  Perhaps you could work through a simple sample problem to illustrate exactly the question you have?